# Receiving image file in paste/drop event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I'm working on a messaging service that allows users to send messages with attachments. I was using an RTE but it added a lot of unnecessary complexity and so now my textbox is just react-textarea-autosize. It is working as expected but when a user pastes/drops an image in to the text box I am trying to capture it and store it in a separate array of files that appears just below the message.
I started using the "onPaste" event, and logging the event shows event.clipboardData as:

```
{dropEffect: "none",
effectAllowed: "uninitialized",
files: FileList {length: 0},
items: DataTransferItemList {length: 0},
types: []}
```

using event.clipboardData.getData("text") returns the correct result if text is copied, and an empty string if an image is copied.
I then attempted to add a separate div that was set to "contentEditable:true" and listen to a paste on that to determine if using a textarea was the issue, and although I could visibly see the image being pasted, but the event still contained no useful data. This also does not work for dropping image files, or dragging and dropping images from other websites.

What gives? I don't understand because the paste event is still firing, I've been testing this mainly in chrome, but firefox also seemed to face difficulties, although it was returning an array of types in the cliboardData object.

Is there anyway to receive an image file that is captured from the paste/drop event?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the files and items show a length of zero, but what I discovered is that the DataTransferItemList doesn't display properties in logs, instead you have to use getter functions as referenced in the MDN Docs. I found a great small example of different Inputs with data transfers.
https://codepen.io/tech_query/pen/MqGgap

```
form.onpaste = form.ondrop = event => {

    if (event.type === 'drop')  event.preventDefault();
    
    const target = event.target;
    
    const cell = target.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll('td');
    
    cell[0].textContent = event.type;

    const transfer = event.clipboardData || event.dataTransfer;
    
    cell[1].firstChild.innerHTML = Array.from(
        transfer.items,  item => `<li>${item.kind} ${item.type}</li>`
    ).join('\n');
};
```